# Does A Product Of Two Element In A Group Create A Third One

Tags: group-theory

It maybe a trivial qeustion, but in a proof I came across the following step.

Let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$, if $b^{-1}a\in H$ there is $h\in H$ s.t $b^{-1}a=h$

Now I know that a subgroup is close to under operation so is it equivalent to say that every product of 2 or more element in a subgroup (or group) create a third element in the subgroup (or group)?

Comment: This isn't a property of closure...this is just what it means to say that $x\in H$.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your question.  Saying that $x\in H$ is equivalent to saying that $\exists h\in H$ such that $x=h$.  This is a set theoretic remark, not a group theoretic one.  As you are not told that $b^{-1}$ or $a$ are in $H$ I don't see what closure under multiplication has to do with anything.

Comment: The statement is confusing precisely because it is tautological. It should just say "Let $h=b^{-1}a$".

Answer (score 2):

Yes (subject to @AnalysisStudent0414's fine point about the possibility that your "third" element might be one of the first two), this is the defining property of a subgroup: it is closed under the group operation. So if 
$$
* : G \times G \to G : x, y \mapsto x * y 
$$
the claim is that the restriction of this operation to $H \times H$ has, as its image, the set $H$ rather than anything else in $G$.

Comment: We aren't told that $b^{-1}$ or $a$ are in $H$ so...

Comment: I was answering the specific question that OP asked: "Now I know that a subgroup is close to under operation so is it equivalent to say that every product of 2 or more element *in a subgroup* (or group) create a third element in the subgroup (or group)?" I'm not certain that this is the OP's real question, but it seemed right to assume so until corrected. :)

Comment: OTOH, your point is a good one: it's possible that OP doesn't yet know to be careful to check that each of $b^{-1}$ and $a$ is actually in $H$, so reinforcing that is probably a Good Thing.

Comment: Makes sense.  By "equivalent" I took it that the OP was suggesting that question was in some way related to the first remark (about $b^{-1}a$).  Of course, that might not be the case.

Comment: Ah. Excellent point.  I suppose that all will be revealed in the fullness of time . :)

Comment: Amazing :) the next step in the lecture note was to take $b^{-1}a=h$ and multiply from the left in $b$, I just sent him a mail asking why can we be sure $b\in H$? we know that $a^{-1}b\in H$ but not $b$

Comment: @gbox  Just to stress (though it is probably obvious), $b^{-1}a\in H$ in no way implies that either term separately is in $H$.  Take $b=a$ for example.  Or $b=ah$ for any $h\in H$.

Comment: @lulu, yes let see what the lecturer answers :) thank you so much for the help, learnt a lot from the discussion

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. "Creating" an element seems to imply that $ab \neq a$, $ab \neq b$ for all $a,b \in G$, while this is not the case when $a$ or $b$ is the identity of the (sub)group.

What is correct is to say that the (sub)group is closed under the (sub)group operation, that is, for every pair of elements $a,b \in H$, there exists an element $c \in H$ such that $ab=c$. 
 In particular, if the product of two elements in the bigger group $G$ happens to be an element of $H$ (for example, because it is the product of two elements already in $H$), you can use the property that $H$ is also a group to say that there is a specific element $c$ equal to that product.